# Divide raster map into segments, maintaining georeference in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, georeferencing

I have some historical maps so heavily distorted that usual rubbersheeting is possible but already quite problematic. I need 400 control points and more, and performance is abysmal, and "local" results in different parts still aren't always great.

It would be much simpler and cleaner to work,  dividing the map in maybe 25 bits, setting the local parts into their context.

Now, I don't want to georeference them all from scratch as finding their position might be a bit tedious. So I thought it would be great to have an initial position for them to start with.

Is there maybe a way to divide a mosaic dataset? I can't find a tool that would help.